# Asp .Net Core Show DateTime based on localization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I want my input to show as dd/mm/yyyy, how i can i change by default?

[image: -]

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy")]
public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
```

html

```
<input asp-for="Process.Date" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that what you're actually referring to is the HTML5 date input and how it's rendered by browsers. What you're seeing *is* localized, but it's localized based on the culture set on the client machine. In other words, you can't control this from the server. That's actually the way it *should* be. The end-user decides their own culture preferences. Additionally, the date input type doesn't support any date format but ISO (YYYY-MM-DD). Passing a date formatted in any other way will be treated as a null value.

If you don't want this behavior, your only choice is to use a regular text input, which you can achieve by manually specifying the `type` attribute:

```
<input type="text" asp-for="Process.Date" class="form-control" />
```

However, when you do this, it's just a regular text input. You will get no date picker control, validation, etc. You'll need to rely on third-party JS libraries to add back in this functionality client-side, if you desire it.

Comment: this is unfortunate, i was trying to get rid of datepicker plugins but i guess i'll still have to use them.